# Best way to wrap certain HTML elements within a HTML String?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a web application where my frontend (React, JavaScript), receives sanitized HTML strings that can contain `<span>` elements.

Example:

`'testing <span id="1">hello world</span> 2222222'`

I am able to display this no problem via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

However, in my frontend, I want to wrap these `<span>`s in another component. For example:

`testing <NicerSpan><span id="1">hello world</span></NicerSpan> 2222222`.

I am able to do this via Regex: create a regexp to match `<span>...</span>`s, split the html string using the regexp, and then iterate through all the matches and wrap it in my desired component:

```
<div>
  {replaceSpans(myHtmlString, (match) => (
    <NicerSpan>{match}</NicerSpan>
  ))}
</div>
```

```
const replaceSpans = (span, matchFn) => {
  const split = span.split(spanRegex);

  // apply fn to all matches (located at odd-indexes)
  for (let i = 1; i < split.length; i += 2) {
    split[i] = matchFn(split[i]);
  }
  return split;
};
```

The RegExp I am using is `/(<span[^>]*>[\s\S]+<\/span>)/g`.

I have created a CodePen that demonstrates the above working: https://codepen.io/dero0/pen/ZEKoYGQ.

You can see the provided `<span>` in the HTML string is now wrapped in another component with a style (the actual component in my application does a bunch of other stuff, this is just an example). In short, I want to wrap the `<span>`s in the HTML string with another component.

However, I feel like this is not a very robust or efficient solution. Is there a better solution for doing this? Ideally without using jQuery.

Thank you!